# is there a java library to access or respond to an ethereum contract events?

Tags: contract-invocation, events, java

We are building a java backend that is expected to interact with an ethereum node. So far I have only seen and tried web3.js api but it seems difficult to run it from java code.

Is there a way to use java to connect to the node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For java there is [web3j on github](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) and its page https://web3j.io/.